# Guides in amcharts: How to use prefixes for disk usage in amcharts: 1024 vs 1000

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to graph disk space usage in amcharts.  My input data is in raw format: bytes.

I would like amcharts to dynamically show the k/M/G/T/P prefixes, and draw the guides on one of those boundaries, ie if the values are in the megabyte range, show 1M 2M 3M etc as guides.

To do so, I'm using the option "usePrefixes" on my valueAxe to make amcharts use prefixes.  When using this option, the prefixes are 1000-based, not 1024-based as required with disk storage.

I've tried changing prefixesOfBigNumbers to

```
[{"number":Math.pow(1024,1),"prefix":"k"},  
{"number":Math.pow(1024,2),"prefix":"M"},  
{"number":Math.pow(1024,3),"prefix":"G"},  
{"number":Math.pow(1024,4),"prefix":"T"},  
{"number":Math.pow(1024,5),"prefix":"P"},  
{"number":Math.pow(1024,6),"prefix":"E"}],
```

but this does not work properly: for example: given data between 0 and 450 megabytes, amcharts will use 100,000,000; 195,312.5k; 300,000,000; 390,625k ; 500 000 000 as guides for the graph, instead of the more logical 100M 200M 300M 400M 500M.

How can I make amcharts guides system use 1024 based guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way to do this is format them yourself as the prefixes only support multiples of 10 as you've noticed.

For axis labels and balloons, you can use the [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ValueAxis#labelFunction) for the value axis and [`balloonFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#balloonFunction) to apply your own formatting. For the guides, you'll have to format those labels before creating them.

There's a demo in AmCharts' knowledge base that takes you most of the way there with the balloonFunction and labelFunction here: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/format-value-axis-and-balloon-numbers-as-file-sizes/ You can take the format method and apply it to your guide labels as well.

Embedded version of the knowledge base demo below:

```js
var chartData = generateChartData();
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "marginRight": 80,
  "autoMarginOffset": 20,
  "marginTop": 7,
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "valueAxes": [{
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "dashLength": 1,
    "position": "left",
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      return formatFileSize(value);
    }
  }],
  "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
  "graphs": [{
    "id": "g1",
    "balloonFunction": function(item) {
      return "File size: <b>" + formatFileSize(item.values.value) + "</b>";
    },
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
    "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "hideBulletsCount": 50,
    "title": "red line",
    "valueField": "size",
    "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true
  }],
  "chartScrollbar": {
    "autoGridCount": true,
    "graph": "g1",
    "scrollbarHeight": 40
  },
  "chartCursor": {

  },
  "categoryField": "date",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "dashLength": 1,
    "minorGridEnabled": true
  }
});

// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
  var chartData = [];
  var firstDate = new Date();
  firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 30);

  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

    var size = Math.round(Math.random() * (500000 + i * 50000));

    chartData.push({
      date: newDate,
      size: size
    });
  }
  return chartData;
}

function formatFileSize(value) {
  if (value >= 1073741824)
    return (Math.round(value / 1073741824 * 100) / 100) + "TB";
  else if (value >= 1048576)
    return (Math.round(value / 1048576 * 100) / 100) + "MB";
  else if (value >= 1024)
    return Math.round(value / 1024) + "KB";
  else
    return value + "B";
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```